# Is there a dependency that can generate dummy data list according to the sampledata used in recyclerview items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, code-generation, dummy-data

So I have been thinking about it for a long time. Is there a way that can generate a `List of Custom Class` according to the `sampledata` used in the recycler view item? It can help in testing UI and save alot time.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/posts_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout_item_post" />
```

For Example in this recycler view i have used `tools:listitem="@layout/layout_item_post"`

In that layout file, I have used these sample data

`tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"`

`tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names"`

`tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"`

What I want is something that can automatically create a custom class from sample data.

```
class Post {
    private String name;
    private String userImage;
    private String postImage;
}
```

If you know about some tool, a dependency that can do that let me know or you can give me some guidance to build it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the same xml attribute in java?

Comment: @FaizanHaidarKhan I'm talking about code generation from sample data. Sample data is not used when you build the application. It's just used for previewing purposes. But if there's some tool that can help in manipulating the sample data and converting it into Custom Class it'll be very time saving.